# Matlab says 'find' is not defined in a function

Tags: matlab

In my command window, I can execute `find([0 1 0])`, but when I run find in a function, as in `x = find([0 1 0])`, the compiler tells me that `find` isn't defined. Why might that be?

The error is:

```
??? Error: File: frequentTuples.m Line: 12 Column: 21
 "find" previously appeared to be used as a function or command, conflicting with its
 use here as the name of a variable.
 A possible cause of this error is that you forgot to initialize the
 variable, or you have initialized it implicitly using load or eval.
```

and here's the code. The error occurs on the second line of the for loop.

```
function [ tuples ] = frequentTuples( k, candidates, transactions, min_support  )
%FREQUENTTUPLES Get frequent itemsets of size k
%   Detailed explanation goes here

candidate_tuple_is_frequent = zeros(size(candidates, 1));
for i = 1:size(candidates, 1)
    columns_of_candidate_items = transactions(:, candidates(i, :));
    indices_of_transactions_containing_all_items = find(sum(columns_of_candidate_items') == k);
    candidate_tuple_is_frequent(i) = size(indices_of_transactions_containing_all_items) >= min_support;
end

tuples = candidates(find(candidate_tuple_is_frequent, :));

end
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the exact code and error message that you're getting?

Comment: I can see no reason why that error would occur from the code you've shown (also, in future it would be better if you included it as code rather than a picture - it makes copying the code to test rather difficult). Just out of curiosity, does the error stay if you replace `[0 0 1]` with a variable?

Comment: I'm guessing that image doesn't show all of the code for the function (some is hidden by the tooltip as well) and that you have somewhere defined a variable of function called `find`.

Comment: @horchler: I'm not convinced that is the case, as the scope of the function clearly starts at line 1 and ends at line 15. Variables defined elsewhere shouldn't affect the code shown.

Comment: warning on line 8 looks weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, I see your problem now. You have a misplaced bracket on line 13. You have

```
tuples = candidates(find(candidate_tuple_is_frequent, :));
```

When you should have

```
tuples = candidates(find(candidate_tuple_is_frequent), :);
```

You're trying to call `find(candidate_tuple_is_frequent, :)`, which is trying to treat find as a variable. This means that any other call to find in the function will treat it as a variable, hence your error.